How can I avoid using pl.DataFrame.iter_rows() and instead vectorize this
I have two polars dataframes containing a unique ID and the name of a utility. I am trying to build a mapping of entries between these two dataframes. I am using polars_fuzzy_match to do a fuzzy string search against entries. My first dataframe (wg_df) is approximately a subset of the second (eia_df). In my code below I am passing each utility_name from wg_df into fuzzy_match_score run against the eia_utility_name. Can I avoid the rowise iteration and vectorize this?
import polars as pl
from polars_fuzzy_match import fuzzy_match_score

# Sample data
#  wg_df is approximately a subset of eia_df.
wg_df = pl.DataFrame({"wg_id": [1, 2], "utility_name": ["Utility A", "Utility B"]})

eia_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"eia_id": [101, 102, 103], "utility_name": ["Utility A co.", "Utility B", "utility c"]}
)

out = pl.DataFrame(
    schema=[
        ("wg_id", pl.Int64),
        ("eia_id", pl.Int64),
        ("wg_utility_name", pl.String),
        ("utility_name", pl.String),
        ("score", pl.UInt32),
    ],
)

# Iterate through each wg utility and find the best match in eia
# can this be vectorized?
for wg_id, utility in wg_df.iter_rows():
    res = (
        eia_df.with_columns(score=fuzzy_match_score(pl.col("utility_name"), utility))
        .filter(pl.col("score").is_not_null())
        .sort(by="score", descending=True)
    )
    # insert the wg_id and wg_utility_name into the results. They have to be put into the 
    res.insert_column(
        0,
        pl.Series("wg_id", [wg_id] * len(res)),
    )
    res.insert_column(2, pl.Series("wg_utility_name", [utility] * len(res)))
    out = out.vstack(res.select([col_name for col_name in out.schema]))


I don't think it's possible as fuzzy_match_score only accepts a single str as the pattern. The plugin itself would need to add support for comparing against another column (like how polars_ds does - but polars_ds doesn't contain this particular fuzzy algorithm that nucleo uses)

polars-fuzzy-match would need to add support for vectorization. (i.e. at the Rust level)
The polars_ds plugin has vectorized functions backed by the impressive RapidFuzz library.
import polars_ds as pds

(eia_df
  .lazy()
  .join(wg_df.lazy(), how="cross")
  .with_columns(
      score = pds.str_fuzz(pl.col.utility_name, pl.col.utility_name_right),
  )
  .collect()
)

shape: (6, 5)
┌────────┬───────────────┬───────┬────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ eia_id ┆ utility_name  ┆ wg_id ┆ utility_name_right ┆ score    │
│ ---    ┆ ---           ┆ ---   ┆ ---                ┆ ---      │
│ i64    ┆ str           ┆ i64   ┆ str                ┆ f64      │
╞════════╪═══════════════╪═══════╪════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ 101    ┆ Utility A co. ┆ 1     ┆ Utility A          ┆ 0.818182 │
│ 101    ┆ Utility A co. ┆ 2     ┆ Utility B          ┆ 0.727273 │ 
│ 102    ┆ Utility B     ┆ 1     ┆ Utility A          ┆ 0.888889 │
│ 102    ┆ Utility B     ┆ 2     ┆ Utility B          ┆ 1.0      │
│ 103    ┆ utility c     ┆ 1     ┆ Utility A          ┆ 0.777778 │
│ 103    ┆ utility c     ┆ 2     ┆ Utility B          ┆ 0.777778 │
└────────┴───────────────┴───────┴────────────────────┴──────────┘

It seems polars-fuzzy-match uses the nucleo library which says it uses the Smith-Waterman algorithm.

rapidfuzz has an open feature request for this algorithm.

It seems like it only gives a scores if they are actual substrings?
(eia_df
  .lazy()
  .join(wg_df.lazy(), how="cross")
  .with_columns(
      score = pds.str_fuzz(pl.col.utility_name, pl.col.utility_name_right),
  )
  .with_columns(
     a = 
        pl.col.utility_name
          .str.to_lowercase()
          .str.contains(
             pl.col.utility_name_right.str.to_lowercase(), 
             literal = True
          ),
     b = 
        pl.col.utility_name_right.str.to_lowercase()
          .str.contains(
             pl.col.utility_name.str.to_lowercase(), 
             literal = True
        )
  )
  .filter(pl.col.a | pl.col.b)
  .collect()
)

shape: (2, 7)
┌────────┬───────────────┬───────┬────────────────────┬──────────┬──────┬───────┐
│ eia_id ┆ utility_name  ┆ wg_id ┆ utility_name_right ┆ score    ┆ a    ┆ b     │
│ ---    ┆ ---           ┆ ---   ┆ ---                ┆ ---      ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i64    ┆ str           ┆ i64   ┆ str                ┆ f64      ┆ bool ┆ bool  │
╞════════╪═══════════════╪═══════╪════════════════════╪══════════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ 101    ┆ Utility A co. ┆ 1     ┆ Utility A          ┆ 0.818182 ┆ true ┆ false │
│ 102    ┆ Utility B     ┆ 2     ┆ Utility B          ┆ 1.0      ┆ true ┆ true  │
└────────┴───────────────┴───────┴────────────────────┴──────────┴──────┴───────┘



https://polars-ds-extension.readthedocs.io/en/latest/string.html#polars_ds.string.str_fuzz
https://github.com/rapidfuzz/rapidfuzz-rs
https://github.com/helix-editor/nucleo
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Waterman_algorithm
https://github.com/rapidfuzz/RapidFuzz/issues/175


This will parallelize the work.
def make_res(wg_id, utility, eia_df):
    return (
        eia_df.lazy()
        .select(
            pl.lit(wg_id).alias('wg_id'),
            pl.all(),
            other_utility_name = pl.lit(utility),
            score=fuzzy_match_score(pl.col("utility_name"), utility),
            )
        .filter(pl.col("score").is_not_null())
    )
    
pl.concat([
    make_res(wg_id, utility, eia_df) for wg_id, utility in wg_df.iter_rows()
]).collect()
    

shape: (2, 5)
┌───────┬────────┬───────────────┬────────────────────┬───────┐
│ wg_id ┆ eia_id ┆ utility_name  ┆ other_utility_name ┆ score │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---           ┆ ---                ┆ ---   │
│ i32   ┆ i64    ┆ str           ┆ str                ┆ u32   │
╞═══════╪════════╪═══════════════╪════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 101    ┆ Utility A co. ┆ Utility A          ┆ 228   │
│ 2     ┆ 102    ┆ Utility B     ┆ Utility B          ┆ 228   │
└───────┴────────┴───────────────┴────────────────────┴───────┘

I don't know anything about this plugin and whether it's expected that both results are 228.
Setting that aside since it's actually not related to the issue, there are two keys to this approach. The first is that we aren't vstacking for every iteration and the second is that when you concat a list of LazyFrames and then collect them, polars will execute each LazyFrame plan in parallel.
